# Why does this python code not swap the numbers?

Tags: python

Why does this python code not swap the numbers?

```
def swap(x, y):
    '''THe swap function'''
    print("INSIDE")
    temp = x
    x = y
    y = temp


#Driver_code
x = 2
y = 3
swap(x, y)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: It swaps them, but in the namespace of `swap()` only. Just use `x, y = y, x` (outside of the function of cause)!

Comment: It does but only in your function. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp)

Answer (score 1):

In the Swap function add this one line:

```
global x,y;
```

The problem is when you are calling the swap() function it is making its own variable x and y,
not using the global variable x and y

Answer (score 0):

Because the swap is inside the function.

You're swapping the values of the function parameters `x` and `y`, which are different from the `x` and `y` that are used below.

Just do this:

```py
x, y = y, x
```

Answer (score 0):

The swap function is not returning values

```
def swap(x, y):
    '''THe swap function'''
    print("INSIDE")
    temp = x
    x=y
    y= temp
    return x,y


#Driver_code
x = 2
y = 3
x,y=swap(x, y)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Here, you assign the returning values to x and y.